# Send the current page as mail or get the Current page html

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I need to send the current page content as a mail. Any Idea How we can Do that. My Idea is to get the html code of the page and send it as such. But Don't know how to get the html code of the page.

Comment: Please don't stack tags in your title - there is no need, you've already added them below.

Comment: Apologies for this slugster... I was not aware of that... Thanks for your replies..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get HTML of your page server side so that you can mail it, Try this

```
StringWriter str_wrt = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter html_wrt = new HtmlTextWriter(str_wrt);
Page.RenderControl(html_wrt);
String HTML =  str_wrt.ToString();
```

Comment: That worked!! But still the style issues as suggested by some members are there.. I am working on it.. Thank You all...

Comment: Change (2nd line) (strwrt) to (str_wrt)

Comment: Saved me big time.  I had to change it up to vars but it worked.

Comment: Just be aware this won't work if you have server-side codes (tags) inside your aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.documentElement.innerHTML to get the page html.

Assuming you are emailing server side, then you would need to post that back so it can be sent.

Comment: He would then have the problem that if the styling is in external stylesheets, those won't be sent with the email and the recipient would get unstyled html.  Which they will then trash.

Comment: @awrigley, yep, thats very true, and then of course there are also any externa image references that won't be included.  The question does only specify they HTML of the page though, and that is all we have to go on.